# MediaWiki variant tabs

Tags: mediawiki

Anyone knows how to get the variant tabs to work as actual tabs and not as a drop down?

This is how sr.wikipedia.org has it:
[image: desired solution, as seen on sr.wikipedia.org]

and this is how I have it on my zablude.com/wiki/ page:
[image]

and I've tried everything I found and searched everywhere I could think of but I wasn't able to find a solution... anyone has any ideas how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They hack it in JavaScript — see this piece of code at the bottom of [Медијавики:Vector.js](http://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%98%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%3aVector.js):

```js
//to be able to switch the language variant (overrides the default buttons with more visible ones)
function tabWorkaround() {
    if(mw.config.get('wgUserVariant') == 'sr') {
        var tab_urls = {};
        tab_urls[0] = document.getElementById('ca-varlang-0').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href; //Ћирилица
        tab_urls[1] = document.getElementById('ca-varlang-1').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href; //Latinica
        $('#p-variants').remove();
        mw.util.addPortletLink('p-namespaces', tab_urls[0], 'Ћирилица');
        mw.util.addPortletLink('p-namespaces', tab_urls[1], 'Latinica');
    }
}
$(document).ready(tabWorkaround);
```

It would probably be cleaner to do it with a MediaWiki hook, though.  The following code is untested, but should work if I haven't made any silly mistakes:

```php
// show language variants as tabs in Vector skin
function tabWorkaround( &$skintemplate, &$links ) {
    $links['namespaces'] += $links['variants'];
    $links['variants'] = array();
    return true;
}
$wgHooks['SkinTemplateNavigation::Universal'][] = 'tabWorkaround';
```

(In MW 1.17, this hook is only called from the Vector skin.  In MW 1.18, it will affect all skins.  If you don't want that, you could test whether `$skintemplate->skinname == 'vector'`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$wgVectorFeatures['collapsibletabs']['global'] = false;`. That is intended for the dropdown on the other side, but might work for other dropdowns as well.

Comment: tried it... (i placed it in LocalSettings.php) and it didn't work for either side...